# How to input an audio file, generate video, split, crop and overlay to output a kaleidoscope effect

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I need to create an FFMPEG script which reads in an audio file ("testloop.wav" in this example) generates a video from the waveform using the "showcqt" filter , and then crops and overlays the  output from that to generate a kaleidoscope effect.  This is the code I have so far - the generation of the intial video and the output section work correctly, but there is a fault in the split, crop and overlay section which I cannot trace.

```
    ffmpeg -i "testloop.wav" -i "testloop.wav" \
-filter_complex  "[0:a]showcqt,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" \
        "split [tmp1][tmp2]; \
        [tmp1] crop=iw:(ih/3)*2:0:0, pad=0:ih+ih/2 [top]; \
        [tmp2] crop=iw:ih/3:0:(ih/3)*2, hflip [bottom]; \
        [top][bottom] overlay=0:(H/3)*2"\
-map 1:a:0 -codec:v libx264 -crf 21 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 -movflags faststart "${i%.wav}.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't split or define multiple filter_complex*es*. Also, no need to feed input twice.

```
ffmpeg -i "testloop.wav" \
-filter_complex  "[0:a]showcqt,format=yuv420p, \
        split [tmp1][tmp2]; \
        [tmp1] crop=iw:(ih/3)*2:0:0, pad=0:ih+ih/2 [top]; \
        [tmp2] crop=iw:ih/3:0:(ih/3)*2, hflip [bottom]; \
        [top][bottom] overlay=0:(H/3)*2"\
-c:v libx264 -crf 21 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -ar 48000 -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

(I'm not debugging the logic of the effect you're trying to achieve. Only the syntax)